# PHP: Multiple conditions with NOT Equal (!=) operator is not working

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-operator

Hope u people will be fine.
I’m working on a following code in which i want to use multiple php if conditions with multiple not operators (example is below), but when i execute following php code, it always returns true (mean content in always parenthesis always executed) even no condition is true.
I want to ask what is the problem in following code. Is there any specific syntax or rule for using multiple != operator in php conditions. And i am amazed to see that if i use following code by replacing != operator with == operator it is working fine.

```
if( $ext!="exe" || $ext!="html" ||  $ext!="htm"  ||  $ext!="js" ||  $ext!="iso" ||  $ext!="zip"  ||  $ext!="rar" )
{ // ececk extension
    echo $ext."extension";

}
else{
    echo "not match";   
}
```

Waiting for your kind replies. and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: If you use `OR (||)` condition means it will check the condition one by one. If your extension `$ext = 'jpg'` means its not equal `$ext != 'exe' (condition true)`, then its omit all those remaining conditions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Better code:

```
$allowed = array('jpeg','png');

if(in_array($ext,$allowed)){
  echo "Correct";
}
else {
 echo "Wrong";
}
```

Comment: How to do it using ternary operator?

Answer (score 0):

User XOR operator instead of OR as or checked all condition need to be identical while XOR return true if anyone from all is identical:

```
  if(!($ext!=="exe") xor ($ext=="html")){ //Add more conditions
    //each condition in new brackets & ! sign in start before all conditions

 { // ececk extension
                echo $ext."extension";

            }
            else{
                echo "not match";   
            }
```

Hope it will help

Comment: This worked for me, thanks for the tip!